# List all subsets of $2\times 2$ rank-1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $C$ be a collection of all rank-1 $2\times 2$ matrices $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{pq}^T$. I am trying to enumerate its subsets $C_1, C_2,....$ like

- $C_1$: Collection of all symmetric matrices  with $a_{ii}=1$ and $\alpha\neq 0$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{pq}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1& \alpha\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& \alpha\\ \alpha& \alpha^2\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

- $C_2$: Collection of all matrices such that $\|p\|_2=\|q\|_2=1$
- $C_3$: Collection of all matrices with $a_{ii}=1$ and $\alpha \neq 0, \beta \neq 0$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{pq}^T=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1& \beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1& \beta\\ \alpha& \alpha\beta\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Can someone help me in enumerating the rest.

Comment: The space spanned by all rank one $\;2\times2\;$ matrices is...the whole space of $\;2time2\;$ matrices.

Comment: Whole space of $2\times 2$ matrices include rank-2 matrices as well. Rank-1 matrices form a subspace $S$ of space spanned by all $2\times 2$ matrices therefore it is not the whole space.

Comment: @NAASI The set of rank-1 matrices does not form a subspace. Neither $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ nor $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is of rank 1

Comment: The zero matrix is not of rank one - which means that $S$ can't be a subspace.

Comment: oh  right. I should have used "set" instead of "space". I have made some edits to fix this

Comment: Unless you impose some conditions, there are going to be infinitely many different subsets of that set...

Comment: Right. $C_1, C_2, C_3$ enumerate some of those conditions. I am looking for some more